# What the best solution for Dropbox in Indicator Applet?

Tags: gnome, indicator, applet, dropbox

I need a solution for Dropbox, i would like to put in Indicator Applet! what the best solution? Tks!

Answer (score 4):

The latest Dropbox experimental version adds AppIndicator support as well as finally allows Linux users to change the notification area icon.
source: http://www.webupd8.org/2010/05/latest-experimental-dropbox-adds.html

[image]

If you don't want to try the experimental version there is a script to install 9 Different Dropbox Indicator Icon Sets In Ubuntu

source: http://www.webupd8.org/2010/07/script-to-install-9-different-dropbox.html

Comment: that script requires the experimental version, please edit your question.